# Not able to upload and save image in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to upload a image in PHP but the image is not getting saved in the directory on the server. However I'm able to save the path of the image in the database. Please help. Here is the piece of code. I'm not getting any error in the web page.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
session_start();

$logged_user_name = $_SESSION['user_name'];
$logged_user_type = $_SESSION['user_type'];
$logged_user_team_id = $_SESSION['team_id'];
$logged_user_team_name = $_SESSION['team_name'];

$uploaded_profile_image = $_POST['propic'];
//$uploaded_profile_image = $_FILES['propic']['name'];

include_once("classes/doEverything_framework.php");

function upload_image()
{
$db_connection_obj = new database_connection;
$db_connection = ($db_connection_obj -> open_database_connection());

global $logged_user_name;
global $uploaded_profile_image;

$profile_image_upload_dir = 'images/uploaded_profile_pics/';


if ($uploaded_profile_image != null || $uploaded_profile_image != "") 
{
    //file_put_contents($uploaded_profile_image);
    move_uploaded_file($uploaded_profile_image, $profile_image_upload_dir);
    //file_put_contents($uploaded_profile_image,$profile_image_upload_dir);

    $uploaded_profile_image_link = $profile_image_upload_dir.$uploaded_profile_image;       

    $sql = "UPDATE user_login_table SET user_profile_image = '$uploaded_profile_image_link' WHERE user_name = '$logged_user_name'";
    mysql_query($sql, $db_connection);
}

$db_connection_obj -> close_database_connection($db_connection);

  }

?>
```

HTML Code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uploadprofileimage" onsubmit="" action="" method="post">
                    <input type="file" name="propic" id="propic" onclick="" >
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload" id="submit" >
                    <br>
                    <label for="propic" id="picerrorlabel"></label>
                </form>
                <?php
                if(isset($_POST['upload'])) //This ensures the function runs only when the submit button is clicked.
                {

                    upload_image();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to access selected File is as follows

```
$uploaded_profile_image = $_FILES['propic']['name'];
```

Make sure you are uploading file within limit of configured file size in php.ini (upload_max_filesize). rest all should work.

Answer (score 0):

**Correction 1:-**

Your are passing only directory name in [move_uploaded_dir](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file). I think you should pass complete image path. and `$uploaded_profile_image` should be your image `tmp_name`.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['propic']['tmp_name'], $profile_image_upload_dir.$uploaded_profile_image);
```

**Correction 2:-** You can't get image name in $_POST. so it should be

```
$uploaded_profile_image = $_FILES['propic']['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get image or any file in $_POST['propic']; the correct way to access file or image is by using $_FILES

so you should use $uploaded_profile_image = $_FILES['propic']['name'] in move_uploaded_file function. Make sure to check upload_max_filesize limit in php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

To upload a file in php use move_uploaded_file()

```
$path="upload/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]; // This specifies the path to save file
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$path);
```

Answer (score 0):

First You cant get file value in POST method so you need to user $_FILE to get file. So you need to replace line no 5 with this :

```
$uploaded_profile_image = $_FILES['propic'];
```

Another mistake in your code is while moving uploaded file where source params is expected to be temporary location of file :

```
 move_uploaded_file($uploaded_profile_image['tmp_name'], $profile_image_upload_dir.$uploaded_profile_image['name']);
```

Now in line no 27 you can get file name to store in database this way :

```
   $uploaded_profile_image_link = $profile_image_upload_dir.$uploaded_profile_image['name'];
```

Comment: @krish if it has worked for you please mark it as accepted so it will be easy for the user having same problem while passing through it